# Constant in Second Order PDE

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this PDE
$$
u_{xy} = x - y
$$

$$ \implies \iint u_{xy}\,dy\,dx = \iint ( x-y )\,dy\,dx$$
$$ = \int (xy - \frac{y^2}{2} + k_0(x))\,dx$$

My question is: How should I proceed? $k(x)$ is a constant with respect to $y$, however it depends on $x$ and it could be any function, therefore I don't know how to integrate it. Should I leave $k_0(x)$ just as a real number or ignore it?

If I ignore it I get:

$$
u(x,y) = \frac{x^2y - xy^2}{2} + k_0(x) + k_1(y)
$$

If I take this $u(x,y)$ and differentiate with respect to $x$ and the with respect to $y$ I would get the original PDE but I don't know how to justify it.

Comment: You have got the correct solution; $k_0$ and $k_1$ are arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.

If $u$ is a sufficiently smooth solution (let's say $C^2(\mathbb R^2)$), then from the condition $u_{xy}(x,y) = x - y$ it follows by integrating with respect to $y$, that $$ \int u_{xy}(x,y)dy = \int (x-y)dy $$
Hence for some constant $C$ (constant with respect to $y$) we have $$u_{x}(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{2} - xy + C$$
The point is, $C$ is constant with respect to $y$, but not a constant (necessarily) with respect to $x$!. So in fact, $C$ is a function of $x$, and it should be written $$ u_x(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{2} - xy + C(x) $$
Note that due to $u_x \in C^1(\mathbb R^2)$ then $C \in C^1(\mathbb R)$, too.
Now, what's left, is to integrate one more time, with respect to $x$ (note we need to integrate function $C$, but it's in particular continuous, hence we can, and let $F$ be such function, that $F'(x)=C(x)$.
Then
$$ \int u_x(x,y)dx = \int (\frac{x^2}{2} - xy +C(x))dx $$
And for some constant $A$ (constant with respect to $x$), but again, not necessarily constant with respect to $y$, so in fact for some function (continuous) $A$ of variable $y$ we have

$$ u(x,y) = \frac{x^2y - y^2x}{2} + F(x) + A(y) $$
Where $F'=C$ and $C \in C^1(\mathbb R)$ (so $F \in C^2(\mathbb R)$ and $A \in C^2(\mathbb R)$
In other words, if $u$ is a solution to your equation (of the class $C^2(\mathbb R^2)$) then there exists two functions of one variable, sufficiently smooth, that is $f,g \in C^2(\mathbb R)$, such that $$ u(x,y) = \frac{x^2y - xy^2}{2} + f(x) + g(y) $$